# Spring Boot : BeanFactoryPostProcessor's postProcessBeanFactory not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

> [Spring constructor injection of SLF4J logger - how to get injection
>   target class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038179/3143670)

I want to achieve similar functionality but in Spring boot.

I tried the solution given for this question but it seems `postProcessBeanFactory` method of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` never gets invoked in my Spring-Boot application

Below is the implementation of method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class LoggerBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        String [] beanClasses = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for(String beanName : beanClasses){
            Object beanObject = beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
            if(beanObject.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Loggable.class)){
                try {
                    Field loggerField = beanObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("logger");
                    loggerField.setAccessible(true);
                    loggerField.set(beanObject, LoggerFactory.getLogger(beanObject.getClass()));
                }catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you added this class into configuration as bean?

Comment: @KenBekov Where exactly i need to add this in a Spring Boot project?

Comment: Add this as a `public static` `@Bean` method to your configuration. Only adding the class will do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Spring should know that you have added a new BeanFactoryPostProcessor, so you should declare this as a bean into your configuration.
For xml config:

```
<bean class="your.package.LoggerBeanFactoryPostProcessor"  />
```

And for JavaConfig:

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor loggerBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
    return new LoggerBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
}
```

Note: be sure to make a method in your JavaConfig that return BeanFactoryPostProcessor static. Without it will work fine until you want to use some other spring related features. For example using property `@Value` won't work.

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

> By marking this method as static, it can be invoked without causing
>   instantiation of its declaring @Configuration class, thus avoiding the
>   above-mentioned lifecycle conflicts. Note however that static @Bean
>   methods will not be enhanced for scoping and AOP semantics as
>   mentioned above. This works out in BFPP cases, as they are not
>   typically referenced by other @Bean methods.

Comment: the XML method BeanFactoryPostProcessor is not called when I use XmlBeanDefinitionReader with DefaultListableBeanFactory, and I can not figure out why?

Comment: @YuJiaao maybe post a separate question with the code example and all the details?

Comment: I post a new question and an example on `github`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640952/how-to-call-beanfactorypostprocessor-postprocessbeanfactory-method-when-use-spri